# Why isn't Core Data inserting this relationship object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an object, `currentWorkout` that is selected from a table in the previous screen, then passed to the current view. The object is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, type `Workout`:

**Workout.h**

```
@class Movement;

@interface Workout : NSManagedObject
// ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *movement;
@end

@interface Workout (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMovementObject:(Movement *)value;
- (void)removeMovementObject:(Movement *)value;
- (void)addMovement:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMovement:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

`Workout.m` only has the `@dynamic` implementations of the properties, no code for the add/remove methods.

The new `Movement` object is created in a modal view. The `MovementList` view controller creates the managed object in `prepareForSegue:`, passes it to the modal view where the information is populated, then returns it back to the `MovementList` view controller using `addMovementViewControllerDidSave:`. It is here that the `managedObjectContext` is saved (in case the user cancels the addition).

**MovementListViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addMovement"]){
        AddMovementViewController *amvc = (AddMovementViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        Movement *newMovement = (Movement *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Movement" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        amvc.movement = newMovement;
        amvc.delegate = self;

        [self.currentWorkout addMovementObject:newMovement];
    }
}

// ...

-(void)addMovementViewControllerDidSave:(Movement *)newMovement{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"New movement: %@",newMovement.name);

    NSError *error;
    if(![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    }

    NSMutableSet *allMovements = [self.currentWorkout mutableSetValueForKey:@"movements"];
    NSArray *movementsArray = [allMovements allObjects];
    for(Movement *test in movementsArray){
        NSLog(@"%@",test.name);
    }

    [self.delegate newMovementAdded:newMovement];
}
```

The problem is that the for loop is never called, because the `movementsArray` is `NULL`. If I try to select the first object created, that also returns `NULL`. Is this an issue with how I'm testing to see if the object was added, or is it something more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your to-many property on Workout appears to be 'movement,' but you are accessing the key 'movements.' Could that be the issue?

Comment: That fixed it. It's weird that it never threw a key-value error.